# ImportError: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, face-recognition

I'm having problems in importing dlib in python3 for face recognition:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dan/PycharmProjects/FaceRecognitionPipeline_GeeksForGeeks-master/FaceClusteringLibrary.py", line 9, in <module>
    import dlib
  File "/home/dan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ImportError: libcusolver.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

```
dan@dan-System-Product-Name:/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64$ ls
libcublasLt.so.11          libcublas.so.11          libnvblas.so.11
libcublasLt.so.11.2.0.252  libcublas.so.11.2.0.252  libnvblas.so.11.2.0.252
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried installing it?

Comment: @Chris yes, ``` dan@dan-System-Product-Name:/usr/local/cuda-11.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib$ ls
libcublasLt.so.11          libcublas.so.11.2.0.252  libnvblas.so.11.2.0.252
libcublasLt.so.11.2.0.252  libcusolver.so.11
libcublas.so.11            libnvblas.so.11
```

Comment: Is the path to your library in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @cup, do I need to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /etc/bash.bashrc ?

Comment: Either add it to your .bash_profile or your .bashrc.  That way, it won't be on the path of those who don't need it.